# How can I bind a Rails 3 route parameter to a nested value in the params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to have a route like this

```
get "users/sms_confirmation/:sms_confirmation_code" => "users#sms_confirmation"
```

bind the `:sms_confirmation_code` param like the following example:

A request to `users/sms_confirmation/ABC123` results in the `params` hash containing

```
{:user => {:sms_confirmation_code => "ABC123"}} # This is what I want
```

Currently the route gives me:

```
{:sms_confirmation_code => "ABC123"} # This is what I've got.
```

As of yet I cannot find a way to do this with Rails 3 routing.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Working around this problem is easy, but I don't want to do it if it's unnecessary.

UPDATE:  `sms_confirmation_code` is a fields in the users table.  My goal is to use pretty URLs such as the one in the example above rather than a query string appended to the URL.  I also want to avoid extra code in the controller to structure a hash like described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sms_confirmation is nested under users right?

shouldn't it be something like`users/123/sms_confirmation/ABC123` ?

```
resources :users do
  resources :sms_confirmation do
    get "users/:user_id/sms_confirmation/:sms_confirmation_code" => "users#sms_confirmation"
  end
end
```

if you don't have a users controller you could use a namespace such as

```
namespace "users" do
 resources :sms_confirmation do
  get "sms_confirmation" => "users#sms_confirmation"
 end     
end
```

Tell me if it worked!

Comment: perhaps my wording of the question was not very clear, please see the update.  I do not mean that sms_confirmation is a nested resource, but rather that I want `:sms_confirmation => "ABC123"` to be nested under the `:user` key of `params` hash.  I'd like to do that without resorting to extra code beyond the route definition.